# Is there a way to delete a folder the same way we delete a file automatically?

Tags: c#, .net, directory, filesystems, delete-file

Using [FileOptions.DeleteOnClose](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.fileoptions.aspx) we can have a file delete itself when the last handle has been closed, this is very useful for temporary files that you want deleted when the program is closed. I created the following function

```
/// <summary>
/// Create a file in the temp directory that will be automatically deleted when the program is closed
/// </summary>
/// <param name="filename">The name of the file</param>
/// <param name="file">The data to write out to the file</param>
/// <returns>A file stream that must be kept in scope or the file will be deleted.</returns>
private static FileStream CreateAutoDeleteFile(string filename, byte[] file)
{
    //get the GUID for this assembly.
    var attribute = (GuidAttribute)Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetCustomAttributes(typeof(GuidAttribute), true)[0];
    var assemblyGuid = attribute.Value;

    //Create the folder for the files to be saved in.
    string folder = Path.Combine(Path.GetTempPath(), assemblyGuid);
    Directory.CreateDirectory(folder);

    var fs = new FileStream(Path.Combine(folder, filename), FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.ReadWrite,
                                   FileShare.ReadWrite, 16 << 10, //16k buffer
                                   FileOptions.DeleteOnClose);

    //Check and see if the file has already been created, if not write it out.
    if (fs.Length == 0)
    {
        fs.Write(file, 0, file.Length);
        fs.Flush();
    }

    return fs;
}
```

Everything works perfectly but I leave a leftover folder in the users `%TEMP%` folder. I would like to be a good citizen and also delete the folder when I am done but I don't think there is a way to do that like I do with files.

Is there a way to auto-delete the folder like I delete the file, or am I just going to have to live with the folder remaining or having to explicitly call `Directory.Delete` when my program closes.

Comment: There is no such concept of "delete directory when it empties" known by NTFS (or exposed in the Windows FS API or directly supported in .NET). I suppose a [FileSystemWatcher](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher.aspx) could be used ..